# Enter text in the app folder

Tags: ios, text

```
- (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)myString {

NSURL *myURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"nombre" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSString *myFileViaURL = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[myString writeToFile:myFileViaURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 }
```

Is also possible to insert text in txt files dragged to xcode.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? What is this I don't even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to change some files in application bundle - it's not possible.
If you want to store some data on your device and be able to change it - you need to save your data in some other place.
You cat try to use something like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  _path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nombre.txt"];

  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_path]) {
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nombre.txt"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:_path error:&error];
    if (success) {
      [myString writeToFile:_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
  }
```